# Рассчитать Field of View у камеры

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет, вообщем вышла вот такая ситуация я создал тему "Как сделать чтобы игра подстраивалась под размеры экрана", мне посоветовали изменять field of view у камеры способ не плохой, но я не знаю как сделать формулу чтобы она рассчитывала field of view в зависимости от размеров экрана
У меня получилась вот такая формула:

```
float startScreenW = 1280,
          startScreenH = 720,
         startFieldOfView = 32;

float cScreenW = Screen.width / startScreenW;
float cScreenH = Screen.height / startScreenH;

Camera.main.fieldOfView = startFieldOfView * cScreenW * cScreenH;
```

startScreenW это стартовая ширина которую я настроил в unity

startScreenH это стартовая высота которую я настроил в unity

startFieldOfView это стартовая FieldOfView которую я настроил в unity

Мне кажется эта формула будет работать не корректно!

А что предложить вы?

Comment: Я предлагаю закрыть тему как таковую, на которую нельзя дать обьективного ответа. А тебе посоветую просто пробовать и коректировать формулу пока не выйдет так как тебе нужно. Здесь оракулов нету что бы наверняка знать что конкретно ты хочешь увидеть, что там у тебя в проэкте и как это сделать. Это подбирается исключительно методом проб и ошибок а не вопросами на SO

Comment: А вы начинайте не с того, как именно вы пытаетесь решить проблему, а как эта проблема возникла. Например, объясните зачем вам эти магические расчеты? Для скейла интерфейса?

Comment: Я хочу сделать чтобы моя 3D сцена подстраивалась под разные расширения экранов. Я уже отчаялся не где нет нормальной инфы об этом

Comment: @AimonZ., не думали о том, чтобы в зависимости от разрешения просто поднимать/опускать камеру? т.е. менять масштаб так, чтобы весь уровень был на экране. Или будет нормальным, что у игрока с меньшим экраном будет меньшее по размерам игровое поле?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в документации) Все подробно описано: [Размер усечённой пирамиды на данном расстоянии от камеры](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html). Можно взять и рассчитать FOV исходя из размеров вашей сцены в пространстве 3D.